# How to make parts of a sprite transparent?

Tags: kivy

I posted the following question at www.reddit.com/r/kivy but nobody could help me.

Let's say I have a red square and I want a hole in it so that the background can be seen through this hole. It ought to be possible to do that but I can't find a way. I found the following snippet but it doesn't work. Is that because it simply couldn't work or because I'm trying to make it work on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 3? I hope someone can enlighten me, thank you in advance.

```
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('img.jpg')
img = img.convert("RGBA")
datas = img.getdata()

newData = []
for item in datas:
    if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
        newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
    else:
        newData.append(item)

img.putdata(newData)
img.save("img2.jpg")
```

With C++ and DirectX there is no problem, one can set a certain colour to be transparent, t.ex white, so that all white pixels in a sprite are not drawn.
The same must be possible for Kivy, but I can't make it work.
I hope someone can explain how it is done. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The jpg format does not support transparency.  You should use a format that does, like png.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I also tried with png, which didn't work either. Can you show me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found a way to make a part of a sprite transparent.
I can't say I understand what's going on, but if the image is a GIF (not a PNG), one can use GIMP (the free drawing program).
Add an alpha channel, delete the part that should be transparent and export the file as a GIF. Then it works.
PNG-files ought to work too but doesn't (at least for me). Maybe it's because I use QPython on my tablet to run Kivy-files.